# Webresource files not loading properly throwing 404 errors then stating the javascript files arent defined below that

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, http-status-code-404, webresource.axd

So I have a page that calls in controls from another solution, aka why the webresource files are needed. These files are javascript files coming in to control the form. For some reason two of the top files dont work and then the bottom two do. Exp:

```
<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=1Tr8Mvsq-xPvHYjU9XJnuFyQ_tbQZbcOPSoApVUD9XtrtDIZiBwervNxtmfmLq-VvuZa_cAkkcEMi1AQ4TmiKFUYEG28ApnhtmKUsQU1wbU1&amp;t=635200758466652144" type="text/javascript"></script> - **DOESNT WORK**


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=5RczNbAFoI0LV2Pnfqj79jxyDouwE3SMdxdvlspER2GAWzRxuEUUrKiFWZWtY9Ea-Gr8iZ38MJVrALxkp4Cz5MfeSYIj4Q9QdafByjgtvJ1I_EZ5qe-TCnYc6bSK8ktE3mevTGeG1rSTpnUunhZmwCYJBxucCls94hCg08s0oOwIM2JdvPyiUZV94NUwT1UOt6WA_vVjQmc4D2r5PyqKmkH0oFwq-8JP8Yvf77pcDDGqWz9htW-UZwBxKDY43Fn9HVJ2V_7M8VI5CbTARvkCdfE00f8sl_iJSg2bKQ5-wL01&amp;t=635346160098280718?1.0.5235.13329" type="text/javascript"></script>- **DOESNT WORK**

<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=HPhniWMBSUGCGQGxsRwIIQwQyQ2mdLNlG0GnxVhLFfWApOkmrr72unlOn8vYGG6aQLUrC9myEBWN8wZkVWtKFsxxeuX7HbuxWMkYFICExc86MjdmH0b0TVgk3ky_O02NEBbaspdm7TQCiA-4SoH_IvXkf3rsHWK-TWqoIQYMHE5weXEgg0xrhPZcWjQ8cMUN-JyfsaNaFrn5MkUJcQt6q-EhT_U_PfDUHWPOpJJAgUaJRTgOuU3y_pYr1nMUuG2W0&amp;t=635346160098280718?1.0.5235.13329" type="text/javascript"></script> - **WORKS**

<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=tB0elUveM8i0js4eoAZE06ABBMb7wzMo6ZCqd6z1bkEqBLy37NIfvwubwu8sDS6fPA0qhO0dgHDtfaCjSzW95PXWmskhbE8Tz4hHzt3OiO9_ZM1mDf0G9TAvxvIO6yU_wyK_6Hx8tb6waqmL-4SekKKv4LzqbAmj4gACw4U2JIL6CtWVAfJEEAmimRJm9l6Bl3vfHtumRD2cTKtdCobtj3IItDoN3HUAjTDiwAqylDrtJi-BAdUjVaK8iw4I6EJmV5cLa09zgIUg6rV4cjsCcQ2&amp;t=635346160098280718?1.0.5235.13329" type="text/javascript"></script> - **WORKS**
```

And then here is the errors I get in the console after the page loads

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.globusfaith.com/general.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/WebResource.axd
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.globusfaith.com/general.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/WebResource.axd
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
Uncaught ReferenceError: WebForm_FireDefaultButton is not defined ?ciid=8385426:25
Uncaught ReferenceError: SubmitPage2 is not defined ?ciid=8385426:556
Uncaught ReferenceError: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: SubmitPage2 is not defined ?ciid=8385426:556
Uncaught ReferenceError: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is not defined
```

Anyone know why some work some times and then not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that created and modified timestamps of dll files in the bin folder of you application are not in the future.